# C# - Are Dynamic Parameters Boxed

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0, boxing

If I have:

```
void Foo(dynamic X) {
}
```

And then:

```
Foo(12);
```

Would 12 get boxed?  I can't imagine it would, I'd just like to ask the experts.

Comment: Why do you imagine it would not? How do you imagine the runtime is storing a value of *unknown compile-time type* if not as an object? (This is not a rhetorical question; I am interested in learning about why people's intuitions lead them to believe false things about language features so that we can try to design better features in the future.)

Comment: Are you on the C# team??  It was not a justified assumption on my part.  With all the amazingly cool features that have been added to C#, it's easy to sometimes forget that C# is still a statically typed language, so how could it *not* be object under the covers.  If you are on the C# team, then thank you for the lambda expressions.  Best language feature ever.

Comment: @Adam: You're welcome. I enjoyed implementing lambda expressions very much and I'm glad you're enjoying using them!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892704/ for more musing on this topic. (That is, the equivalence of dynamic and object.)

Comment: I agree lambda expressions are seriously very cool. I use it all the time. It's these kinds of things that makes C# my favorite language. That and .NET.

Comment: Eric, I know this is partially off-topic, but is there any chance C# 5 will support calling extension methods dynamically?  It's not a huge deal, but could be useful in some areas.

Comment: @Adam: Possible, but unlikely. We'd need a mechanism whereby the dynamic site could tell the runtime version of the compiler precisely what "using" directives were in what namespaces, and we have no such mechanism at this time. The cost of the feature is relatively high and the benefits aren't huge, so it's not very high on the priority list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it will.

Under the hood, a `dynamic` type is just an `object` with some meta-data, so value-types will get boxed when put into a variable, field, or parameter of type `dynamic`.

The method will actually be compiled as this:

```
void Foo([Dynamic] object X)
{
}
```

Read more about the [DynamicAttribute here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute.aspx).

IL for code calling it:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.s 12
    L_0003: box int32
    L_0008: call void ConsoleApplication13.Program::Foo(object)
    L_000d: nop 
    L_000e: ret 
}
```

Comment: I had a sinking feeling that would be the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A value type needs to be boxed in order to type check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes !

Since its a value type, it will be boxed.