# Cast GenericClass<T> to GenericClass<dynamic>

Tags: c#, generics, casting

How I can cast to a
    `GenericClass<T> object to GenericClass<dynamic> object` 
T can be any type "dynamic" is new type in .Net

Comment: You can't, in general. You can where `T` is a reference type if `GenericClass<T>` is *actually* an interface or delegate type and `T` is covariant... e.g. for `IEnumerable<T>`. And `dynamic` isn't really a type in .NET, as such. It's a *sort* of type in C# which changes how the compiler operations, but it's not a CLR type. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: why not make this an answer Jon?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892704/why-is-dynamic-not-covariant-and-contravariant-with-respect-to-all-types-when

Comment: I created a type GridViewPageModel<T> for showing generic ViewModels in asp.NET MVC but problem is  it is not possible to set @model as Generic so I set model as GridViewPageModel<dynamic> but it gives casting error while binding GridViewPageModel<MyViewModel> object

Comment: Is casting `GenericClass<T>` to `GenericClass<object>` possible?