# In C# Convert List<dynamic> to List<string>

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a `List<dynamic>` object containing strings:

```
var dlist = new List<dynamic>()
{
    "test",
    "test2",
    "test3"
};
```

Is there any efficient way of converting this into a proper `List<string>` object? I know I can iterate over this list and cast each element to a string, then add this to the result list, but maybe some Linq magic could do the trick in one line?

I tried using some `Select()` combined with `ToList()` and `Cast<string>`, but to no avail. How should this be done properly?

**Note**: By saying "efficient" I mean of course number of lines of code. I do not take execution time or performance into account. Also - let's suppose I do not need to type check, there will always be strings only in this dynamic list.

EDIT: Okay, so in regards to comments on "why Cast wasn't working for you" - looks like I had another problem regarding the data I receive (I'm using Dapper) and that's why it didn't work. Sorry for the confusion, I thought my list converting was wrong while the problem was not related to this.

Comment: Just `dlist.Cast<string>().ToList();` should do.

Comment: When you know the type, why even use `dynamic` in the first place?

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you mean by "but to no avail".  What happened?

Comment: TimSchmelter: Edited the post to add clarification for "efficiency".
@HimBromBeere I receive this list from other source, it's not dependant on me.

Comment: You still didn´t clearify what "doesn´t work" mean. What actually *is* your problem on this question?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I did. It's working as intended, I had an issue that is not related to converting and it mislead me into thinking that I'm doing something wrong on converting part. I believe this question can be left as is for reference on proper casting List of dynamics to list of given type, can't it?

Comment: @Evk tried your method, not working

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Given

```
var dList = new List<dynamic>() { /*...initialize list */ };
```

If you are interested in extracting all the strings in the collection, ignoring all other types, you can use:

```
// Solution 1: Include only strings, no null values, no exceptions thrown
var strings = dlist.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

If you are certain that all the items in the list are strings (it will throw an exception if they are not), you can use:

```
// Solution 2: Include strings with null values, Exception for other data types thrown
var strings = dlist.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

If you want the default string representation, with `null` for `null` values, of all the items in the list, you can use:

```
// Solution 3: Include all, regardless of data type, no exceptions thrown
var strings = dlist.Select(item => item?.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Or [`dlist.Cast<string>()`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IJ4rab). But since OP already tried it, it would be interesting to know why it didn't work. `OfType` just comes in handy if there are other types in the list which OP has not mentioned.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please see my "Edit" part. I appended some clarification on why I got this wrong - looks like I was looking for solution X when the problem was Y.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, I might be wrong, but I don't find the explanation clear enough. OfType<string>() will return unboxed versions of all the "boxed" strings in the collection while ignoring any other type, while Cast<string> assumes that they are all boxed strings

Comment: @AlexC. boxing/unboxing is for `object`s, not `dynamic`s. However, you are correct that `OfType` will return only actual `string`s while `Cast` will fail if there are non-`string` values

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If Eric Lippert is wrong about this (dynamic vs object), I don't know who would be right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892704/why-is-dynamic-not-covariant-and-contravariant-with-respect-to-all-types-when

Comment: @AlexC. Thanks for the edit, and you are right about that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto My pleasure! I just wanted to improve the answer for future generations! :)

Comment: Thats perfect and the easiest solution for my problem

Comment: Good answer. Let me add something: Solution 1 just returns items if they are strings, will suppress null values and numbers. Solution 2 includes null values, but will throw an exception if there are numbers, Solution 3 works with everything, including null values and numbers (tested with .NET core using LinqPad 6).

Answer (score 36):

> This answer is for `dart/flutter`

Given

```
List<dynamic> dList;
```

You can use

```
var sList = List<String>.from(dlist);
```

to convert a `List<dynamic>` to `List<String>`

Comment: `.from(...)` doesn't work for me. I tried it in LinqPad. Anything missing? (using ...)

Comment: Haven't parsed in a while, totally forgot! THANKS!!! HAHA, it is in the C# section, this is dart syntax, it lead me here!!! No wonder it has so many up votes, probably from dart/flutter people.

Comment: @serg I am getting `error CS0117: 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'from'`