# dynamic.ToString() unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, string, dynamic, tostring

I'm wondering how does this code work:

```
dynamic dynaString = 2;
string b = dynaString.ToString();
```

When this one is not working:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
var liststring = new List<string>();
liststring = list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
```

I know I can add `Cast<string>` after Select statement but that does not explain that behaviour. Why does `ToString()` on dynamic element work different when called on dynamic variable declared in code than on dynamic variable taken from list in LINQ.

I've looked into method signature of `Select` and it's:

[image]

My guess is that `x` here is a dynamic variable, so it should behave just like `dynaString`, but it's not. Intellisense is suggesting me that this `x.ToString()` returns `string`:

[image]
[image]

Anyone got experience with dynamics in C# and can explain me that?

---

I've also tried this code:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
var liststring = new List<string>();
foreach (dynamic a in list)
{
    liststring.Add(a.ToString());
}
```

It compiles as expected, because again the `a` is declared as dynamic in foreach statement.

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

Comment: @SᴇM following your suggestion I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893408/1714342 but still it does not completely answer my question. "Everywhere that you have a type argument that is "dynamic", the compiler simply generates "object" as a type argument. "dynamic" is a C# language feature" is not a case here. You can change all dynamics here to object and it'll compile, while with dynamics it won't :)

Comment: I'm not sure it answers your question, but the return type of `aDynamic.ToString()` is dynamic, so the `Select<dynamic, dynamic>` is inferred.. you wouldn't then expect it to be possible to assign a `List<dynamic>` to a `List<string>`. If you specify `Select<dynamic, string>` instead, that should work.

Comment: @steve16351 Funny... It creates even more questions :) Why compiler does not choose `<dynamic,string>` instead of `<dynami,dynamic>`? I've tried `liststring = list.Select<dynamic,string>(x => x.ToString()).ToList();` and it compiles as you said :)

Comment: The return type of `ToString()` on a dynamic object is the dynamic type still. It has to infer the `Select` generic types at compile-time, and it won't know it's a `String` until run-time, without the hint.

Comment: @steve16351 I agree, but it can infer type from result type expected, I guess.

Comment: Yes, it *could*, but I believe that would be inferring based on the return type, which [isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why).

Comment: @wudzik: _Why compiler does not choose...?_  **The dynamic type indicates that use of the variable and references to its members bypass compile-time type checking.** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-dynamic-type

Answer (score 0):

According to [dynamic type docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-dynamic-type):

> The dynamic type indicates that use of the variable and references to its members bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.
>
> Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. In particular, any non-null expression can be converted to the dynamic type. The dynamic type differs from object in that operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the compiler.

There is no way to infer type from usage in case type checking and/or resolution is bypassed at compile-time.

If you omit generic type parameter it will by default return `dynamic` type even you call `ToString()` method. The reason is that any non-null expression can be assigned to `dynamic`. As `dynamic` is source, it will be also the result of `Select(x => x.ToString())` method call.

On the other hand you can assign `dynamic` object to `string` variable as you are calling `ToString()` which returns `string` instance.